# font in SCSS issue

Tags: css, sass

my scss code is:

```
.icon-download:before {
  content: "\f01a"
}

.icon-upload:before {
  content: "\f01b"
}
```

and I use ruby to translate to css:

```
.icon-download:before {
  content: "    "
}

.icon-upload:before {
  content: "    "
}
```

I do not know why the content is empty.

the problem is shown in below picture：
[image]

thanks to connexo . my compiling is ruby on win10.

```
es\Jianux>scss -v
Ruby Sass 3.5.7
```

Comment: Which SCSS compiler exactly are you using? sassmeister.com has some for choice. Also, maybe your IDE's font simply doesn't show the characters (compiling your source will make Sass replace your character code by the corresponding character).

Comment: thanks to connexo . my compiling is ruby on win10.

    Ruby Sass 3.5.7

Comment: I just use the command line to complie it： sass input.scss output.css

Comment: thanks a lot， I use nodejs-sass to complie it ，and  it is no problem. so zhe compile tools has bug.

Comment: Does your css work as intended? Maybe it's just your font not showing the characters.